# ValidError, invalid input, x is constant

Tags: dependent-variable

how shall I investigate the data and preprocess? I'm trying to do a heatmap analysis of cointegrated pairs using pvalues.

Perform cointegrated pairs analysis
cointegrated_pairs = [] correlation_matrix = np.zeros((len(tickers), len(tickers))) for i, ticker1 in enumerate(tickers): for j, ticker2 in enumerate(tickers): if i != j: p_value = cointegration_test(returns[ticker1], returns[ticker2]) #Error comes here if p_value < 0.01: cointegrated_pairs.append((ticker1, ticker2)) correlation_matrix[i, j] = returns[ticker1].corr(returns[ticker2])

The error message Invalid input, x is constant for the ticker pair (GME, GME) indicates that the exogenous variable (x) in the linear regression model for this pair is constant. This means that the variable does not vary across observations, which can lead to problems with the model estimation and interpretation.

i tried continuing with for i, ticker1 in enumerate(tickers):
for j, ticker2 in enumerate(tickers):
if i != j:
p_value = cointegration_test(returns[ticker1], returns[ticker2])
p_values.loc[ticker1, ticker2] = p_value
but previously, i managed to run a heatmap analysis without any problem, I don't understand why this time GME,GME cointegration returns error.